# Convert .NET framework version for ASP.NET webforms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a very old webforms application, developed on .NET framework version 2.0

Now I want to change it to some newer version of .NET (4.5 or 4.8).

After some research I found a tool on msdn website (Upgrade Assistant) but it does not properly migrate the solution properly. There were a lot of dll related issues after conversion. Note - it does not support ASP.NET webforms/website template for conversion.

Apart from this, how can I upgrade the framework without breaking the code base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention or note if this is a asp.net web site, or a asp.net web site application.

You can determine the difference in that an "application" will have a .sln project file, and a asp.net web site will not have a project file.

So, for a asp.net web site project, then you open the project by opening the .sln file.

For a asp.net web site, then you go file->open web site from Visual Studio.

I would also VERY much consider using VS2019 in place of VS2022. There are a number of reasons for this suggestion, one being that vs2019 is x32 bits (in most cases). Where as vs2022 is now x64 bits. In most cases the fact of vs2022 being x64 bits is not a huge deal, but your use case is one such exception.

Ok, with above information out of the way?

Open the project (using one of the correct 2 choices above).

At this point, why not try increasing the .framework setting. You currently have .net 2.0, and you could try simply changed that to say .net 4.0. If that builds and compiles, then try .net 4.8.

You find that option here:

[image]

You also don't mention if the current project builds and runs correctly. That is a BEYOND important detail here.

In other words, I would not attempt the above change in the .net framework if the current project does not build.

I would also consider forcing the project to x32 bits (x86), since many of the assemblies and referenced libraries may well be only x32 bits with such an older project and framework. Of course, this issue would already have surfaced if you can't build the project as .net 2.0 in the first place.

So, I would try changing the specified .net framework, and see if the project can build. Often (in most cases), such projects can and will build correctly when you change/specify a newer version of the .net framework.

In other words, a "conversion" process is not required in most cases, but only you changing (increasing) the chosen version of .net used to build the project. You could consider changing from 2.0 to say 3.5, and build the project. If you only receive 1 or 2 small errors? Then fix those 2-3 errors. Now, you can increase the project to say .net 4.0, and do the same. And at that point, if the project builds as .net 4.0, then it most likely will build and run fine as .net 4.8.

Comment: On the very first line , its mentioned as web form application

Comment: that is good news! So, make a copy of the project, and try bumping up the .net framework, and see what happens. Assuming it builds with .net 2.0, then try 4, and see if it can build. If it builds, then you just upgraded to .net 4.0. Or try even 4.8.

Comment: That I did already, converted to 4.8. Was working fine in VS 2010 but not in VS 2022. As per your suggestion I installed VS 2019 and it compiled. It was x86 version issue.

Comment: Ok, you "might" get this to work in vs2022, but one thing at a time. vs2022 while a x64 bit product will in general correctly build and compile - and if the project is x86, then all the more so. However, there are some cases, due to vs now being x64 bits, that this may well not work. However, I currently run/debug, and maintain some older projects, and I am doing so with vs2022. So, as noted, vs2022 may well be able to build, but you need to do some further testing. Regardless, if you were able to update the .net version and build ok, then you upgraded to a later/newer version of .net anyway

Comment: Just a quick question. if any referenced dll in that project is not compatible with new version that it will stop project from build or they will show error at runtime ?

Comment: I was targeting to upgrade on .Net 7.o (sdk style project) but even the upgrade-assistant does not support asp.net web form template, it only support MVC, WebAPI project.

Comment: no, .net core is a 100% different issue and beast. There is no support for web forms in .net core right now. You are to stick to .net framework for webforms at this point in time. If you want to adopt .net core, then you have to dump web forms, and re-write the whole application as MVC - a mountain of work. So, no automated conversion exists here, and it never did, or will.

Comment: As for referenced .dlls? If the project builds, then it will to my knowledge then just work. As noted, this suggests that even vs2022 can work as long as you force the project to x86. In most cases. .net 4.0, or even 4.8 runtimes can execute .net 2.0 code.  So, once that project works under vs2019, then it probably can be opened and used with vs2022. The big "issue" with vs2022 is how it creates NEW projects, and as a result it will not allow selection (down grade) to previous .net versions. However if the project was already created (pre vs2022), then vs2022 is more flexible.